# What was the first recorded reference to the fact that the sun rises and sets at different times across the Earth?

Tags: astronomy

I am just wondering that when was first time people actually got to know the timezone difference, Day night difference in the human history?

Comment: Not the same from place to place, or not the same at different times of the year?

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify where you've searched and what you found already, complete with links and references, and context if applicable? In particular, please let us know what you find missing or unclear about the Wikipedia entry on the topic, if one exists. This allows those who might want to answer to do so without needing to redo the work you've already done. You might find it helpful to review the site [tour] and [help] and, in particular, [ask].

Comment: When you say timezone difference, that makes me think longitude. But late summer sunsets and early winter ones are about latitude. Which are you asking about?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if they were the first, but ancient Greeks clearly had the idea based on Wikipedia's [history of longitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_longitude#Ancient_history)

> Eratosthenes in the 3rd century BC first proposed a system of latitude and longitude for a map of the world. [...] 
>   By the 2nd century BC Hipparchus [...] proposed a method of determining longitude by comparing the local time of a lunar eclipse at two different places, to obtain the difference in longitude between them. This method was not very accurate, given the limitations of the available clocks, and it was seldom done - possibly only once, using the Arbela eclipse of 330.

If anyone noticed much earlier than this, I would suspect the Babylonians, but I am not finding any direct reference to support that they did.